# Как спарсить динамический контент сайта znanija

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу код на питоне, который парсит ответы на вопросы с сайта znanija.com без просмотра рекламы, но данный сайт использует динамический контент. Я
подгружал контент после просмотра рекламы и смотрел во вкладке *Network* все *js* словари в *XHR*, но не в одном не нашёл подгружающий *html* или текст с ответом. Я заходил по ссылке изучал словарь и не находил класс блока с ответами. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как парсить этот сайт, желательно с помощью `requests` и `bs4`?

Comment: что конкретно хотите спарсить? покажите адрес страницы и ваш код?

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://znanija.com/task/37248755 мне нужен ответ на вопрос, но получать его можно только если зайти менее двух раз, дальше только через просмотр рекламы. На данный момент кода у меня нет, я ищу что нужно парсить.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Ищите сперва не в js-ках, а в ответе самой страницы (в Elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с простого:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://znanija.com/task/37248755'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
answer = soup.find('div', class_='js-answer-content')

print(answer.text)
```

Выведет:

```
Ответ:( -2 ; 3) ∪ ( 3; +∞) Пошаговое объяснение:Подкоренное: > потому что в знаменателе не может быть 0 2х+4>0 2х>-4х>-2модуль х ≠ 3 х≠± 3( -2 ; 3) ∪ ( 3; +∞)
```